# Passing JSON strings larger than 80 characters

Tags: python, string, json, size, max

I'm having a problem passing strings that exceed 80 characters in JSON. When I pass a string that's exactly 80 characters long it works like magic. But once I add the 81st letter it craps out. I've tried looking at the json object in firebug and it seems to think the string is an array because it has an expander next to it. Clicking the expander though does nothing. I've tried searching online for caps on JSON string sizes and work arounds but am coming up empty :(. Anybody know anything about this?

edit:

It actually doesn't matter what the string is... using "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" yields the same results.

Here's my code: (I'm using python)

result = {"test": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(result))

would you happen to know the class that encodes strings properly for python? Thanks so much :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it craps out"?

Comment: Should we assume parsing in JavaScript?  What, exactly, is the error?

Comment: There is no way that there is a limit of 80 characters; by way of example my JSON parser written in Java set no limits at all, other than physical RAM and the 2GB array limit implicit in Java.

Comment: craps out as in throws exception

Comment: Could you post more detail like what the exception is? I tried what I think is the same thing and it worked fine.

Comment: Even better would be a link to an example page.

Comment: simplejson.dumps works fine here.  perhaps the problem lies with whatever self.response.out.write() is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the 81st character? Sounds like the string isn't properly escaped, making the json decoder think it is an array. If you could post the string here, or at least the 20 or so characters around 80, I could probably tell you what is wrong. Also, if you could tell how the json string was made. In most languages you can get a class that will make proper json strings out of objects and arrays. For example, php has [json_encode();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)